# Camelot Error: The client was not authorised by the server. Ensure that the ConnectionString property on the Connection is correct

Tags: sharepoint, camelot-.net-connector

I'm getting the error when connecting to SharePoint

I am sure that my connection string is correct, this is how I connect

```
var connectionString = "Server=mysharepointserver.com;User=spuser;Password=******;Authentication=Ntlm;TimeOut=10;SSL=True;RecursiveMode=RecursiveAll;DefaultLimit=1000;CacheTimeout=5";

using (var connection = new SharePointConnection(connectionString)) // This is where it breaks
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SharePointCommand("SELECT * Tasks", connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["Title"].ToString().PadRight(40) + " : " + reader["Country"].ToString());
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

The error occurs when loading the connectionString into the SharePointConnection

Here is the full error
    The client was not authorised by the server. Ensure that the
    ConnectionString property on the Connection is correct.

```
at Camelot.SharePointConnector.Data.SharePointCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
  behavior, Boolean returnScalar)
at Camelot.SharePointConnector.Data.SharePointCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(
  CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
  behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[]
  datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand
  command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord,
  Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
at Camelot.SharePointConnector.Data.Helper.ExecuteDataTable(String query, String
  connectionString)
at Camelot.WebParts.BlogReader.BlogReader.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually means that the

- credentials in the connectionstring is wrong, or
- connection wasn’t allowed from the client
- the authentication didn’t succeed from a client that is on a different domain

**Credential management**

It is important that the parameters in the connectionstring are correct, if you have used authentication=default you may try using the authentication=ntlm instead and remember to check and recheck that your user have access rights to the specified SharePoint Server and Site

**Allowing connections**

There is something called “loopback errors” that occurs internally in Windows. There are a lot of articles on how to work with this; we prefer the simple approach to solve this by using PowerShell

Execute the following PowerShell command on each SharePoint frontend server.

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -Value "1" -PropertyType dword
```

In some very rare occasions you may need to reset IIS.

More reading at Microsoft

- http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;896861
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308